# update item in array in Vue didn't update it in html but it updates value in cli

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, vue.js

i have project single web application coded in Vue js i have array of object that rendered as list of objects in html when update any object by assign new value to index of object didn't render changes in html but i see update from cli

sample of code `this.chatRoomsArray[index] = {name:"ahmed",id:10,read:true}`;

Comment: Could you provide some code, please?

Comment: sample of code this.chatRoomsArray[index] = {name:"ahmed",id:10,read:true}; https://stackoverflow.com/users/10038915/jns

Comment: @mooody Pl edit the question and add code to it. You're more likely to receive good answers if you're specific about the problem with code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this.$set :

```
this.$set(this.chatRoomArray,index,{name :Ahmed, id:10,read:true })
```

Comment: thanks you made my day :)https://stackoverflow.com/users/8172857/boussadjra-brahim